# 4ビットchar型をmapのキーとしたmapを参照できない

Tags: c++, c++11

C++でchar型マップを作成しました。しかし参照できません。

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

const map<char, char> M{
  {0x0, 0xc},
  {0x1, 0x5},
  {0x2, 0x6},
  {0x3, 0xb},
  {0x4, 0x9},
  {0x5, 0x0},
  {0x6, 0xa},
  {0x7, 0xd},
  {0x8, 0x3},
  {0x9, 0xe},
  {0xa, 0xf},
  {0xb, 0x8},
  {0xc, 0x4},
  {0xd, 0x7},
  {0xe, 0x1},
  {0xf, 0x2}
};


int main(){

  cout << static_cast<bitset<4> > (M[0x0]) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

下記エラーが出てしまいます。

```
test.cpp:46:40: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const map<char, char>'
  cout << static_cast<bitset<4> > (M[0x0]) << endl;
                                   ^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:1006:18: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
      'const map<char, char>', but method is not marked const
    mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& __k);
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:1008:18: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
      'const map<char, char>', but method is not marked const
    mapped_type& operator[](key_type&& __k);
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

このようなmapを使うことはできますか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map`は`const`にすることはできません。なぜなら

```
M[0x10] = 0;
```

のように新たな要素を挿入できるようにするために`operator[]`は非constとなっているからです。メンバー関数`at()`であれば挿入を行わずconstバージョンも用意されているため

```
cout << static_cast<bitset<4> > (M.at(0x0)) << endl;
```

とできます。

---

ただし正直言って4bit＝16要素であれば二分探索する`std::map`よりもO(1)でアクセス可能な`std::array`をお勧めします。こちらであれば意図通り`const`にもできますし、`operator[]`によるアクセスもできます。

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const array<char, 16> M{ 0xc, 0x5, 0x6, 0xb, 0x9, 0x0, 0xa, 0xd, 0x3, 0xe, 0xf, 0x8, 0x4, 0x7, 0x1, 0x2 };

int main(){
    cout << static_cast<bitset<4> > (M[0x0]) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。このarrayを使ってみます。

Answer (score 2):

`operator[]`はconst版がありませんのでconstな`map`には使えません。

代わりに`at()`を使ってください。

```
int main(){

  cout << static_cast<bitset<4>>(M.at(0x0)) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
constでは使えないのですね。